# How should shufflePlaylist work in the javascript?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

What is the right way to set it up?

Like this?

https://jsitor.com/E8JILS8mzZ

```
function shufflePlaylist(player) {
    player.setShuffle(true);
    player.playVideoAt(0);
    player.pauseVideo();
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
    shufflePlaylist(player);
  }
```

or should it be written like this?

https://jsitor.com/HjrwEdaVqe

```
let hasShuffled = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    player = event.target;
    const shufflePlaylist = true;

    if (!hasShuffled) {
      player.setShuffle(shufflePlaylist);
      player.playVideoAt(0);
      hasShuffled = true;
    }
  }
```

or is there a more proper way for the code to be written?

YouTube Documentation:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

Comment: is this some sort of library? what does the documentation say?

Comment: Here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference?hl=en

Comment: thanks, but I don't need to read the documentation